# WCF SOAP XML parent tag remove

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I am having a problem, i have to remove the encloseing tag, my operation contract is :

```
public List<MessageStatus> sendMessages(List<MessageTO> messages)
```

and the XML formed after adding it in SOAPUI output is given below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sms="https://sms.responsetek.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sms:sendMessages>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <sms:messages>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <message>
               <mid>?</mid>
               <oa>?</oa>
               <da>?</da>
               <text>?</text>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <exp>?</exp>
            </message>
         </sms:messages>
      </sms:sendMessages>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to remove `<sms:messages>` tag from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication69
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement messages = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "messages").FirstOrDefault();

            messages.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this. We don't have any xml. XML is actually wsdl which is automatically generated when we try to call sendMessages operation. We want to generate it without <sms:messages> tag

Comment: I don't know if it is easier to remove it from SOAPUI, or removing it from the output.  You can use XDocument.Parse(string) and remove it from the string  instead of the file.